# PHP get sub array dynamically

Tags: php, arrays, dynamic

I have an array (which will be dynamically populated) called `$currentTree`

Now I want to use this array to iterate over and another array called `$tree`

So, for example

```
$currentTree = array(5, 6, 2, 8);
```

becomes

```
$tree[5][6][2][8] = "hello world"; //the values of $currentTree is used to get the appropriate child node of array $tree
```

Is there any predefined PHP function I can use to achieve this?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: why do you want to do that? i'm sure there will be better approaches than that;

Comment: I tried using array push, but that completely deletes the node and makes a new array in it's place.

Comment: is the format of fetching array index the same or varying.? Eg: for 5,6,2,8 array index will be 2,3,4,5.

Comment: No, for 5,6,2,8 the array index will also be 5,6,2,8. Basically I'll get the array index from the other array

Comment: @hassan Actually I'm making a command line tool for Magento 1.9, and this is apparently the only way of achieving what I want

Comment: You mean there's another array from which $currentTree is getting populated?

Comment: No, currentTree will be populated from a REST API (using Magento). That will return an array, it's just a one time call. But it is dynamic, i.e, I don't know the length or the elements of the array which the API will return

Comment: And that can contain -ve values, so you want to create $tree values using only +ve values.isnt it?

Comment: Yes. The `-1` would just be the default value. It may be ignored. I edited my question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use reference, here is the **[live demo](https://eval.in/755016)**

```
<?php
$currentTree = array(-1, 5, 6, 2, 8);
$ref = &$tree;
    while($v = next($currentTree))
    {
      $ref = &$ref[$v];
    }
    $ref = "hello world";

    print_r($tree);
```

Comment: Also, could you please explain what the `&` does? Is it a pointer reference?

Comment: here is the & reference manual http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.php